# creating output with biber that contains year/address rather than date/location

Tags: biber

I managed to extract all references from a document by calling:

```
biber --output_format=bibtex main.bcf -O hpsg-handbook-bibliography.bib
```

But the output that is created contains `location` and `date` rather than `address` and `year`. Is there a way to make biber create the more oldschool version of bibtex entries?

Comment: Also asked at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/322, where the Biber developer built in a new function for this.

Comment: It would be nice if you could ask PLK to provide an answer or write a self-answer demonstrating the new feature in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The developer of biber was so kind to add an option to create output with the old field names:

```
--output-field-replace=location:address,journaltitle:journal --output-legacy-dates
```

See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/322